# kableExtra::collapse_rows does not work properly with longtable headers that are multiple lines

Tags: r, knitr, kableextra

`kableExtra::collapse_rows` does not seem to correctly place the row group name 
 on subsequent pages when using `knitr::kable(longtable = T)`. `collapse_rows()` row group name overlaps with longtable headers and are not repeated on subsequent pages. See top of pages 2 & 4 when rendering MWE as pdf.

MWE

```r
    library(dplyr)
    library(knitr)
    library(kableExtra)
    # example data for a very long and wide table with nested rows groupings
    set.seed(99112)
    d <- merge(expand.grid(a = c("X", "Y"), b = c("a", "b"), y = 2011:2018),
               data.frame(d1 = rnorm(5),
                          d2 = rnorm(5),
                          d3 = rnorm(5),
                          d4 = rnorm(5),
                          d5 = rnorm(5),
                          d6 = rnorm(5),
                          d7 = rnorm(5),
                          d8 = rnorm(5),
                          d9 = rnorm(5),
                          d10 = rnorm(5)))%>%
          arrange(a, b, y)

    # long header names that need to take two lines
    names(d) <- c("Exches and\nWhyze", "Ehhze and\nBeeze", "Year", paste0("Deeze\nRnorm", 1:10))

    # table
      kable(d,
        longtable = TRUE,
        booktabs = TRUE,
        linesep = '',
        align    = c(rep("l",3),rep("c", ncol(d)-3)),
        caption  = "Collapse rows group name overlaps with longtable headers and are not repeated on subsequent pages.",
        escape        = FALSE, format = 'latex', row.names     = FALSE)%>%
        add_header_above(header = c(rep(" ", 3), "Group 1" = 4, rep(" ", ncol(d) - 7)), bold = FALSE, line = TRUE, align = "c")%>%
        add_header_above(header = c(rep(" ", ncol(d)- 5), "Group 2" = 3, "Group 3" = 2), bold = TRUE, line = TRUE, align = "c")%>%
        add_header_above(header = c(rep(" ", 3), "Group 4" = ncol(d) - 3), bold = TRUE, line = TRUE, align = "c")%>%
        kable_styling(position = "center", latex_options = c("HOLD_position", "repeat_header"), font_size = 6, full_width = FALSE)%>%
        column_spec(1:2, bold = T, width = "1cm", border_right = T) %>%
        column_spec(3:ncol(d), bold = F, width = "1cm") %>% 
        collapse_rows(columns = 1:2, valign = "top", latex_hline = 'major', custom_latex_hline = 1:2)%>%
        landscape()
```

[image: groupnamenotdisplayedproperly]

Comment: See https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/314

Comment: Ah, OK, sounds like this is a known issue and is related to LaTeX and not `kableExtra`.

Comment: Yeah, one thing you can try is to use basic latex tables instead of booktabs. That might help but will create other issues on other parts. So as far as I know there is no good solution until the author of makecells fix it.